# How to use Fiscal Year values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I am working with some historical data on fiscal transfers in Canada. The downloaded data is in the format of fiscal year i.e.

```
Year     Quebec  Alberta
1980-1981   2000    4000
1981-1982   3000    6000
```

I am using the pandas library. However, when I try to make any visualizations using either matplot or sns, it generates an error either not recognizing 'Year' as a numerical value or ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Year'). However, when I change the values in the csv to a single year i.e.

```
Year     Quebec  Alberta
1980    2000    4000
1981    3000    6000
```

it works perfectly fine. Is there a way for Python to treat fiscal year values like 1980-1981 the same as normal year. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2years [periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-span-representation), but if print DataFrame columns cannot see end year:

```
print (df)
   Year  Quebec  Alberta
0  1980    2000     4000
1  1981    3000     6000
    
df['Year'] =  df['Year'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='2A-DEC'))
```

---

```
print (df['Year'])
0    1980
1    1981
Name: Year, dtype: period[2A-DEC]

print (df['Year'].dt.to_timestamp('A', how='s'))
0   1980-12-31
1   1981-12-31
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df['Year'].dt.to_timestamp('A', how='e'))
0   1981-12-31 23:59:59.999999999
1   1982-12-31 23:59:59.999999999
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I think most easier is create 2 columns for start and end year:

```
print (df)
        Year  Quebec  Alberta
0  1980-1981    2000     4000
1  1981-1982    3000     6000

df[['StartYear','EndYear']] = df['Year'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
print (df)
        Year  Quebec  Alberta  StartYear  EndYear
0  1980-1981    2000     4000       1980     1981
1  1981-1982    3000     6000       1981     1982
```